# Big O notation is O(nlgn) same as O(n+nlgn) in terms of computational complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I working on a problem for which I came up with two algorithms: one takes `O(n lgn)` time but requires extra space and other takes `O(n+nlgn)` time. So just wanted to ask is `O(n lgn)` time complexity an improvement over `O(n+nlgn)` or both will be considered equal considering `nlgn` is the biggest value.

Comment: Yes, the `n lg n` term grows faster than `n`, so `O(n + n lg n)` is exactly the same as `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28n%2Bnlogn%29%2F%28nlogn%29%2C+n+-%3E+%2Binf

Comment: It's important to note that when discussing big-O notations, we're talking about *asymptotic* complexity

Comment: For a practical algorithm choice, I would evaluate actual time and space for the expected range of problem sizes. Constant factors and small problem sizes matter. It is also useful to look at asymptotic complexity to avoid nasty surprises if the problem size grows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same:

```
n + n lg n <= 2 n lg n   -- for n >= base of logarithm
            = O(n lg n)
```

Comment: That, plus the lower bound n lg n < n lg n + n, means that Theta(n lg n) = Theta(n lg n + n).